# ORA-00001: unique constraint violated when inserting 0 rows

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, oracle12c, unique-constraint, dml

I am trying to insert 0 rows into a table that has a unique constraint and I am getting ORA-00001: unique constraint violated...

Below is the PL/SQL block I've used to hopefully capture the issue well

```
declare
  l_cnt number;
begin
  set transaction isolation level serializable;
  
  select count(*) into l_cnt from test_view;
  
  dbms_output.put_line('count = ' || to_char(l_cnt));
  
  insert into <table>(<columns>)
    select <columns> from test_view
    log errors ('run1')
    reject limit 0
  ;
  
  dbms_output.put_line('success');
  
exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('ERRROR!');
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
    rollback;
end;
/
```

This is the output

```
count = 0
ERRROR!
ORA-00001: unique constraint (<SCHEMA>.<CONSTRAINT>) violated
```

And sure enough, there is a record in the `ERR$_<table>` table...

If I add `where 1 = 0` to the in the insert statement, everything works, nothing is inserted.

I still don't believe what I am seeing :)

`Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`

---

### Update 1

Below sample without using `count(*)` on the view as this could lead to a different query plan that selecting all required values for the insert.

```
declare
  l_cnt number;
begin
  set transaction isolation level serializable;
  
  insert into testx_table
  select * from testx_view d;
  
  select count(*) into l_cnt from testx_table;

  dbms_output.put_line('count = ' || to_char(l_cnt));

  insert into <table>(<columns>)
  select * from testx_view d
  log errors ('run2')
  reject limit 0;

  dbms_output.put_line('success');

exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('ERRROR!');
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
    rollback;
end;
/
```

### UPDATE 2

I was able to reproduce the behaviour.

```
CREATE TABLE A(ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY)
/

CREATE FUNCTION F(ID_ NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
AS
  L_ID NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT ID INTO L_ID FROM A WHERE ID = ID_;
  RETURN L_ID;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
/

BEGIN
  DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG('A');
END;
/

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO A VALUES (1);
  
  INSERT INTO A SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE F(1) IS NULL
  LOG ERRORS INTO ERR$_A;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
/

SELECT * FROM ERR$_A
/
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74325/1)

And it all boils down to querying table that is being modified from within the function. The functions throws the `ORA-04091: table A is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` but the code catches all exceptions and returns null.

Obviously, selecting from table that's mutating is a nono and must be fixed.

And I am quite angry as I cannot count the number of times I told my collegues to stop using `exception when others then return null`. This is again an example where it completely masked the issue and I've spent the whole day deubgging it.

Comment: `reject limit 0` means that no errors are allowed, so obviously it will stop at the first error. Are you looking for `reject limit unlimited`?

Comment: No, I am expecting there are no errors. I am using the log errors just to see what is going into the table. My problem is there should be nothin inserted into the table, the query returns 0 rows...

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) of the `select count(*)`. It is not so uncommon to get a wrong `count(*)` due to corrupted *index*. You should also realize that you can't get a meaningfull response without showing some details of the view. E.g. I suspect if you `select *` you see some data.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber thanks for pointing out `count(*)` could give different results that selecting all the values. However, even when I insert all the data into a different table using exactly the same query I can see that there are 0 rows (see my updated question)... If I do `select * from testx_view` I see 0 records...

Comment: Please show the constraint.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] that includes: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements for your tables and for logging; the DML (`INSERT`) statements to replicate your sample data; an executable PL/SQL script that we can be run against that initial setup that replicates the issues (preferably as text in the body of the question and a link to a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18), or equivalent, so we can see it running). Please help us to help you by removing the hurdles that will stop us simply and easily replicating your issue and from being able to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select returned 0 rows, that was ok.

However when inserting rows to table, we were actually querying the same table through a function. The function returned `ORA-04091: table A is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` but it was catched in an exception block and `null` was returned. This caused the query to return rows...

## Never use `exception when others then return null`!!!